# Show that any measurement where the measurement operators and the POVM elements coincide is a projective measurement

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, povm, projection-operator

The following question is exercise 2.62 from Nielsen and Chuang's "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information"

Show that any measurement where the measurement operators and the POVM elements coincide is a projective measurement.

I have let $E_{m}=M_{m}$.

Show that $M_{m}$ is a projector:

- $E_{m}=M_{m}$ so $M_{m}=M_{m} ^{T*}M_{m} $, this means that $M_{m}$ is positive and therefore \textbf{Hermitian}
- Easily follows that $M_{m} ^{2} = M_{m}$, so $M_{m}$ is \textbf{indempotent}

So I have shown that $M_{m}$ is a projector.

I then used the fact that $\sum_{m}E_{m}=I$ to prove that the measurement operators satisfy the completeness relation $\sum_{m} M_{m} = I$.

The only thing left (as far as I am aware) to prove that this would be a projective measurement, would be to show that the set $\{M_{m}\}$ is orthogonal. I am not sure how to do this? I assume it comes from the completeness relation and the fact that $M_{m} ^{2} = M_{m}$ but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented on one of your other questions, this is not really a condition, because it is a consequence of the other conditions. So it's not something you have to prove as an extra. Instead, you want to be able to prove the general property.

So, Consider the operator $M$ where $M^2=M$. This means it has eigenvalues $0,1$. Let $|\psi\rangle$ be an eigenvector of eigenvalue 1. Now let's evaluate
$$
\langle\psi|\sum_nM_m|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|I|\psi\rangle=1.
$$
The left-hand side is $\langle\psi|M|\psi\rangle+\sum_{i=2}^N\langle\psi|M_i|\psi\rangle$. Since $\langle\psi|M|\psi\rangle=1$, it must be that
$$
\sum_{i=2}^N\langle\psi|M_i|\psi\rangle=0.
$$
Moreover, since the $M_i$ are positive semi-definite, $\langle\psi|M_i|\psi\rangle\geq0$. The only way this can be satisfied is with $\langle\psi|M_i|\psi\rangle=0$.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the step where we split $$\newcommand\bra[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle} $$ $\bra{\psi}\sum_{n}M_{m}\ket{\psi}$ into $\bra{\psi}M\ket{\psi} + \sum_{i=2}^{N} \bra{\psi}M_{i}\ket{\psi}$.

Comment: I'm just separating out the term $M=M_1$ from the rest of the sum.

Comment: Yes, thanks you! Why does this prove it is orthogonal? If $$\newcommand\bra[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle} $$ $\bra{\psi}M\ket{\psi}=1$ and $\bra{\psi}M_{i}\ket{\psi}=0$, why does this mean that the operators are orthogonal?

Comment: because $M=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ (by spectral decomposition) so $\langle \psi|M_i|\psi\rangle=tr(MM_i)=\langle M,M_i\rangle_F=0$ for all $2\leq i\leq m$ is what it means for $M$ to be orthogonal to $M_i$ for $2\leq i\leq n$.